# my.cnf being ignored (fedora)

Tags: mysql, fedora, my.cnf

Because I'm getting `errno=24` on a few queries in my testing environment (Fedora 18 running `mysql-server.x86_64 5.5.31-1.fc18`), I'm trying to increase the open files limit for mysqld.

I have already changed the OS limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and switching to the mysql user I can test with `ulimit -a` that they did take effect.

I have also added the following to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
#...
open_files_limit = 10000
```

and restarted the service (and even the physical machine) multiple times, but checking the variables while the server's running, `open_files_limit` is always 1024. I tried `open-files-limit` as well, since some of the examples I found online conflicted or were ambiguous, but with the same result.

Thinking maybe the file wasn't being read, I tried adding another variable, and sure enough, if I add and change other variables, they are updated in the runtime variable values, but never the `open_files_limit`.

So my next thought was that maybe the `my.cnf` file is being superseded by another one somewhere else on the system, but

```
[root@host /]# find . -name "*y.cnf"
./etc/my.cnf
```

So I don't think there are any other cnf files (plus, the locations listed at the [dev site](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000) don't have it).

I'm at a loss- what could be causing mysql not to accept the value for `open_file_limit`?

Comment: What did you put in `limits.conf`?

Comment: `limits.conf` has `mysql soft nofile 24000` and `mysql hard nofile 32000`. For the moment, I'm more interested in getting it to take new values than picking optimal ones.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
```

```
# For example, if you want to increase mysql's open-files-limit to 10000,
# you need to increase systemd's LimitNOFILE setting, so create a file named
# "/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/limits.conf" containing:
#       [Service]
#       LimitNOFILE=10000
```

Comment: On fc21 does not work :(